# How can you perfectly centre a grid within a container without using CSS Grid or flexbox?

Tags: html, css, alignment

Okay, so I thought that the grid was perfectly aligned to the center, only to realise that it was a few pixels out. I completely stripped all of my attempts at centering and looked online but couldn't find anything.

I know I can use CSS Grids, Flexbox etc. but I am trying to learn how to create websites without using any aid. So I can learn the reasoning behind things.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8L9ye7nj/5/

Grid HTML:

```
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box" id="stethoscope">
      <div class="box-label">
        <p>Book an appointment</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="prescription">
      <div class="box-label">
        <p>Request a repeat prescription</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="group">
      <div class="box-label">
        <p>Join the Patient Group</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Grid CSS:

```
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #252625;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0.5%;
}

.box-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box-label:hover {
  animation: box-stretch 1s forwards ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box-container {
  width: 90%;
}

.box-container::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.box-wrapper {
  background-color:  #B21645;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How can you divide the box and center them?**

You can use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to use mathematical expressions to calculate height, widths etc in css. You can divide the width by three here for the box.

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
```

**Things to consider**

- Mind the space between inline-block elements. You can read more about
  that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).
- Avoid using floats as much as possible. Most layouts done with float can be achieved with inline-block. Floats are simply meant to take an element, put it to one side, and let other content flow around it.  That’s all.
- `box-wrapper` and `box-container` either one is only needed to wrap the contents inside.

**Code Snippet**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box-wrapper {
  background-color: #b21645;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: left top;
}

.box-label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: padding 0.3s;
}

.box-label:hover {
  padding: 25px 0;
}

.box-label p {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509027572446-af8401acfdc3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ef8f839186c5a6055d2802005b575194&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="" />
    <div class="box-label">
      <p>Some Title Here</p>
    </div>
  </div><div class="box">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509027572446-af8401acfdc3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ef8f839186c5a6055d2802005b575194&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    <div class="box-label">

      <p>Some Title Here</p>
    </div>
  </div><div class="box">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509027572446-af8401acfdc3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=ef8f839186c5a6055d2802005b575194&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="">
    <div class="box-label">
      <p>Some Title Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. The inline-block thing doesn't seem to be working out for me but I'm trying to figure that out. If I wanted to make the boxes not fill up 100% of the screen I would still need an additional wrapper, right?